# Querying Views in Couchbase, Java Client

Tags: java, scala, couchbase

I'm using the 1.4.3 version of the java client and am attempting to connect to the Couchbase server I have running locally but I'm getting auth errors. After looking through the code (isn't open source great?) of how their client library is using the variables amongst their classes I've come to the conclusion that if I want to be able to connect to a "bucket" that I have to create a user for each "bucket" with the same user name as that bucket. This makes no sense to me. I have to be wrong. Aren't I? There has to be another way. What is that way?

For reference, here is what I'm using to create a connection (it's Scala but would look nearly identical in Java):

```
val cf = new CouchbaseConnectionFactoryBuilder()
    .setViewTimeout(opTimeout)
    .setViewWorkerSize(workerSize)
    .setViewConnsPerNode(conPerNode)
    .buildCouchbaseConnection(nodes, bucket, password)
new CouchbaseClient(cf)
```

which follows directly from their [examples](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4/#configuration).

**Their Code**

If I look into the code in which they're connecting to the "view" itself I see the following:

```
public ViewConnection createViewConnection(
    List<InetSocketAddress> addrs) throws IOException {
  return new ViewConnection(this, addrs, bucket, pass);
}
```

which is then passed to a [constructor](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/release14/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/ViewConnection.java):

```
public ViewConnection(final CouchbaseConnectionFactory cf,
                      final List<InetSocketAddress> seedAddrs, final String user,
                      final String password) //more code...
```

and that `user` variable is actually used in the HTTP Basic Auth to form the Authentication header. That `user` variable being, of course, equivalent to the `bucket` variable in the [CouchbaseConnectionFactory](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/release14/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/CouchbaseConnectionFactory.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - each bucket should be authenticated with the bucket name as the user. However, there aren't any users to 'create' - you're just using whatever (bucket) name and password you setup when you created the bucket on the Cluster UI.

Note that people usually use one bucket per application (don't think bucket == table, think bucket == database) and so you wouldn't typically need more than a couple of buckets for most applications.